# Find center point of TouchImageView using TouchImageView.java class

Tags: java, android

I have two TouchImageView. What I want to achieve is that, When I swipe first TouchImageView from left to right, second TouchImageView get swiped right to left automatically. I am using TouchImageView.java class which I have founded at GitHub. Below is my code.

activity_main.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    tools:context="com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.MainActivity" >

    <com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_to_be_zoomed"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/fb" >
    </com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.TouchImageView>

    <com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_to_be_zoomed_mirror"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/fb" >
    </com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.TouchImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo;

import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.TouchImageView.OnTouchImageViewListener;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TouchImageView img_to_be_zoomed;
    TouchImageView img_to_be_zoomed_mirror;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        img_to_be_zoomed = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_to_be_zoomed);
        img_to_be_zoomed
                .setOnTouchImageViewListener(new OnTouchImageViewListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onMove() {

                        img_to_be_zoomed_mirror.setZoom(img_to_be_zoomed);

                        Log.e("X Scroll Point: ",
                                "" + img_to_be_zoomed.getScrollPosition());
                    }
                });

        img_to_be_zoomed_mirror = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_to_be_zoomed_mirror);
        img_to_be_zoomed_mirror
                .setOnTouchImageViewListener(new OnTouchImageViewListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onMove() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        img_to_be_zoomed.setZoom(img_to_be_zoomed_mirror);
                        PointF s = new PointF();
                        PointF q = new PointF();
                        s = img_to_be_zoomed.getScrollPosition();
                        q = img_to_be_zoomed_mirror.getScrollPosition();
                        img_to_be_zoomed.setScrollPosition(s.x
                                - (q.x - img_to_be_zoomed.getX()), s.y);
                        Log.e("img_1", s.x + "/" + s.y);
                        Log.e("img_2", "" + q.x + "/" + q.y);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

TouchImageView.java

[TouchImageView.java Find Here](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java)

**Edit:**
*I have solved problem using below code in MainActivity.java.*

```
PointF pointF_img1 = new PointF();
pointF_img1 = img_to_be_zoomed.getScrollPosition();
img_to_be_zoomed_mirror.setScrollPosition(1 - pointF_img1.x, pointF_img1.y);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved problem using below code in MainActivity.java.

```
PointF pointF_img1 = new PointF();
pointF_img1 = img_to_be_zoomed.getScrollPosition();
img_to_be_zoomed_mirror.setScrollPosition(1 - pointF_img1.x, pointF_img1.y);
```